# Authorization Header Always Undefined when Creating Database Object on User Signup

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm working on a user registration feature for my application, and I'm encountering an issue with the authorization header being consistently undefined when trying to create a database object after a user signs up. I've provided the relevant code below:

```js
const createUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password, data) => {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPasswordFirebase(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            const _authUser = userCredential.user; // Get the user from userCredential
            return createNewUserDBObject(_authUser, data); // Return a promise
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error creating user:', error);
        });
};

const createNewUserDBObject = async (authUser, data) => {
    try {
        const idToken = await authUser.getIdToken();
        const result = await axios.post('/api/users', {
            data: data,
            headers: {
                authorization: `${idToken}`,
            },
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating user object:', error);
    }
};
```